# MYSQL - Find two rows that share the same index

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table that is called ChatParticipants, which has the following columns:
chatId (int - index),
userId (int - index)

`+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| userId                      | chatId                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|             5               |              98              |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|             10              |              98              |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+`

And a chats table in addition to the former one.

If for instance I am a user with id #5, and I would like to chat with a user with id #10, I'd like to know if me (id: 5) and my friend (id: 6) are participating in a chat together, how's that query possible to be done?

Comment: Post the sample data and expected output.

Comment: @ObsidianAge No idea how to approach this one. The only way I could think of is the worst practice - To iterate all the users chats and find if both of the users has a common chat through foreach within foreach. I'm sure that there has to be an elegant approach to this, using a single query

Comment: @GurV the expected output could be the common chat ID between the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u1.chatId 
FROM
  ChatParticipants u1,
  ChatParticipants u2
WHERE u1.userId  = 5
  AND u2.userId  = 6
  AND u1.chatId = u2.chatId
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bc431/1

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!